# How to find a pattern in C++ string

Tags: c++

given a string like `std::string str = "imsi-07353644748"`, I have to verify that after the "-", there are only numbers. I tried to do `str.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) == 4` but it doesn't work cause it's correct also if `str="imsi-abcdef"` when after the "-" there are letters. Do you have any other suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Find the `'-'` in the string. Then from that position onward use `std::isdigit` for each character.

Answer (score 0):

The method `find_first_not_of()`, checks for the first character in the string that does not belong to the specified characters in the argument. However, it starts this check from the beginning of the string, which is not what you want.

You can consider the following approach:

1. First, find the position of the `"-"` in the string. You can use `std::string::find` to achieve this. If there isn't any, return false immediately.
2. Next, Iterate over each character after the hyphen. Starting from the character right after the hyphen, go through each character until the end of the string.
3. Finally, check if all characters are digits. For each character you visit, check if it's a digit. If you encounter a non-digit character, immediately return `false`. You can use `std::isdigit` to cehck whether the character is a digit.

Here's an example code snippet implementing this approach:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool areDigitsAfterHyphen(const std::string& str) {
    std::size_t hyphenPos = str.find("-");
    if (hyphenPos == std::string::npos) {
        // No hyphen was found in the string
        return false;
    }

    for (std::size_t i = hyphenPos + 1; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        if (!std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(str[i]))) {
            // Found a non-digit character after the hyphen
            return false; 
        }
    }
    // All characters after the hyphen are digits.
    return true; 
}
```

**Note**: the function call `std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(str[i]))` is checking if the character at index `i` in the string `str` is a digit. The `static_cast<unsigned char>` part is used to ensure that the character is cast to `unsigned char` before it's passed to `std::isdigit`.

This is done because the behavior of `std::isdigit` (and other functions in `<cctype>`) is undefined if the argument's value is neither representable as `unsigned char` nor equal to `EOF`. To avoid this undefined behavior, characters are explicitly cast to `unsigned char`. ([Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit))

You can use the following code snippet to test this function:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::string str1 = "imsi-07353644748";
    std::string str2 = "imsi-abcdef";

    if (areDigitsAfterHyphen(str1)) {
        std::cout << "String 1: All characters after the hyphen are digits.\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "String 1: Non-digit characters found after the hyphen.\n";
    }

    if (areDigitsAfterHyphen(str2)) {
        std::cout << "String 2: All characters after the hyphen are digits.\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "String 2: Non-digit characters found after the hyphen.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but you can use a regex.

```
#include <regex>

std::regex re("imsi-[0-9]+");
std::cmatch m;
if (std::regex_match(string_you_want_to_check, m, re)) {
    // Yes, it's in the correct format
}
else {
    // Nope
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact you can write a function that also works at compile time.
I prefer using std::string_view is a view on a string already in memory and so it avoids the need of constructing and or copying of std::string. So it is pretty efficient and works with "C" style strings, std::strings as input.

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

// constexpr functions can be checked at compile time and runtime
static constexpr bool validate(std::string_view text)
{
    // bailout early if input too short
    if (text.size() < 3ul) return false;

    auto pos = text.find('-');
    if (pos != std::string_view::npos)
    {
        ++pos; // skip '-' itself
        text = text.substr(pos); // shrink the string_view
        auto pos = text.find_first_not_of("0123456789"); // check if a non digit can be found.
        return (pos == std::string_view::npos); // and return the result
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(validate("imsi-123"));
    static_assert(validate("jmsi-123"));
    static_assert(validate("isbn-1234567890"));
    static_assert(!validate("imsi-a23"));
    static_assert(!validate("imsi--23"));
    static_assert(!validate("imsi-12!"));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply combine `std::all_of` with either `std::string::starts_with` or `std::find`, depending on whether you need to match a specific prefix or any prefix ending with `-`.

The following code does not check for empty substrings, but the logic could easily be adjusted...

```
bool Test1(std::string const& val)
{
    using namespace std::string_view_literals;

    constexpr auto Prefix = "imsi-"sv;
    return val.starts_with(Prefix) && std::all_of(val.begin() + Prefix.size(), val.end(), [](unsigned char c)
        {
            return std::isdigit(c);
        });
}

bool Test2(std::string const& val)
{
    auto pos = std::find(val.begin(), val.end(), '-');
    return (pos != val.end()) && std::all_of(pos + 1, val.end(), [](unsigned char c)
        {
            return std::isdigit(c);
        });
}

int main()
{
    std::cout
        << std::boolalpha
        << Test1("imsi-07353644748") << '\n'
        << Test1("imsi-073536447a48") << '\n'
        << Test2("a-1") << '\n'
        << Test2("a-1o1") << '\n'
        ;
}
```